"Unhandled exception in Script" on PyQt5 exe file
I've been trying to create an exe file through pyinstaller for my PyQt5 program. However, even after the exe file was create, everytime I tried to run it it gave me this error:

Failed to execute script pyi_rth_pyqt5 due to unhandled exception: cannot execute runtime hook for PyQt5 because runtime hook for PyQt6 has been run before, and pyinstaller frozen applications does not support multiple Qt bindings on the same application!

I tried my best to remove any pyside and pyqt6 only modules as I'm only focusing on pyqt5 modules before creating the exe file so I'm not sure what I'm missing. Do I have to install those modules again just so it can run well? Are the frozen applications causing this? While I was using pyinstaller, I've seen "hidden imports" coming out as non-existing from the terminal so I'm not sure if that's the root of the problem and if so, how can I fix this.

Check the imports (especially if they use third party modules), and ensure that they do not even try to import other Qt versions. Without knowing more about your code, we really can't help you, unless you provide a proper [mre] (please do read that link, we do not need the full code).
